# Rails - Where condition on array of ids doesn't run the whole array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-5, conditional-statements, where-clause

In my application, I'm doing a `where` condition in my `user` model with ids *(around 1000 ids)* as below:

```
ids = "1,2,3,4,5,6,... # to 1000"
users = User.where(id: ids.split(',').map(&:to_i) )
```

*Ruby Output of [input.split(', ').map(&:to_i)](http://repl.it/repls/NonstopIdolizedOpenlook) in repl.it*

But when I run this, it only runs the first 108 ids and *ignores* rest of the ids.

Is there any limitation on it or am I doing something wrong?

*PS:
It doesn't return any error, it just runs the first 108 IDs only*

**SQL Output**
`User.where(id: ids.split(',') ) .to_sql`

```
SELECT `user`.* FROM `user` WHERE `user`.`id` IN (1,2,3,4....1000)
```

Any tips are appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: `ids` is an array of integers - why do you split them and convert to integers?

Comment: What do you man it runs only the first 108? What is the SQL query that is generated.

Comment: Because of the way, they get stored. They get stored as a string at first in database :)

Comment: What does `User.where(id: ids.split(',').map(&:to_i) ).to_sql` return?

Comment: We don't know how you store ids - the code example you showed have `ids` as an array of integers and it's quite confusing. Please adjust the code to resemble your actual scenario.

Comment: `<array of integer>.split(',').map(&:to_i)` isn't valid Ruby code (it throws a NoMethodError).

Comment: Thanks @SebastianPalma & mrzasa, I included the sql output into the question

Comment: @mrzasa I changed it format

Comment: @SebastianPalma please check this link https://repl.it/repls/NonstopIdolizedOpenlook for `<array of integer>.split(',').map(&:to_i)`

Comment: That's not an array of integers, is a string.

Comment: Try just `User.where(id: ids.split(', '))`, it doesn't matter if the column is integer or varchar, Rails will handle that when using `where`.

Comment: @SebastianPalma Yes, I saw i wrote it incorrectly and changed the question before that. Thanks for the tips, I'll change that, but my problem is that `where` condition still only takes the first 100 and so ids and not the full list :/ is there any limits

Comment: Difficult to know without all the information.

Comment: @SebastianPalma What other information is needed?

Comment: The block of code where the error is raised and the __whole__ backtrace.

Comment: @SebastianPalma That's the thing, there is no erros getting raised. only thing is that I can see that it doesn't run all the 1000 elements in the ids array

Comment: @SebastianPalma just in general, is there any limitation of the number of elements in a `array` that `where` can *run*?

Comment: As far as I know, no. Add the logs when that code is executed then.

Comment: Thanks @SebastianPalma I'll do that

Comment: @Rubioli: it _runs_ all of them. As evidenced by your generated query. Maybe there's just that many records in your DB.

Comment: So many questions here, why are you storing the ids as a comma separated string in the first place? If its some legacy piece of junk and the decision has already been made why not use a subquery and get the string and split it in the database with something like `regexp_split_to_array`?

Comment: Is there a default scope on the user that might be limiting the return?